# how to avoid flickering between the pages

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile, flicker

I am using jquery mobile and html5.
when i redirect from one page to another page , getting a white screen (flickering).
So how to get out of this problem.

Here is my code..
--Page1--

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Login</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no"  />
     <meta name="x-blackberry-defaultHoverEffect" content="false" />
     <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
     <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

    <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/Global.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
    /*********Page bind evnet --start--********/
            $(document).bind("pageinit", function () {

             $("#login").unbind("click").click(function () {
                                Login();
                        });
        });
    /*********Page bind evnet --Ends--********/


     var Type;
                    var Data;
                    var Url;
                    var DataType;
                    var ContentType;
                    var ProcessData;
                    var Method;
                    jQuery.support.cors = true

                  function Login() {
                        Type = "POST";
                        Url = "/login";                        
                        Data = '{}';
                        DataType = "JSON";
                        ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
                        ProcessData = true;                        
                        CallLoginService();
                    }

                function CallLoginService() {                       
                        $.ajax({
                            type: Type,
                            data: Data,
                            dataType: DataType,
                            processData: ProcessData,
                            url: Url,
                            contentType: ContentType,
                            crossDomain: true,
                            success: function (jsonObj) {

                                if (jsonObj.GetLoginResult[0].Status == "true") {                                  
                                    $(location).attr('href', 'City.html');                                    
                                }
                                else if (jsonObj.GetLoginResult[0].Status == "Invalid username") {
                                    ShowErrorMsg(jsonObj.GetLoginResult[0].Message, '#alertcontainer1');
                                }
                                else {
                                    ShowErrorMsg(jsonObj.GetLoginResult[0].Message, '#alertcontainer1');
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                                CheckNetwork();
                            }
                        });
</script>
    </head> 

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="header">
                <p style="color:#13a5db;">&nbsp;Login</p>            
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
             <div id="alertcontainer1" >
               <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                            <a data-role="button" id="login" data-theme="b">Login</a>
                            <a data-role="button" href="Registration.html"  data-transition="slide" data-theme="b">Register</a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
          <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
             <p>&nbsp;CopyRight &reg; 2013</p>
         </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

page2--(city.html) second page

```
<html> 
   <head>
  <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     /*********Page bind evnet --start--********/
     $(document).bind("pageinit", function () {
       //code
   });
     /*********Page bind evnet --Ends--********/
  </head>
  <body>
  //code
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: what browser did you test this on?

Comment: Maybe the //code of your second page is too slow. Maybe the browser is old, or it does not have good support, maybe the device is too slow. Try removing the page transitions.

Comment: I deployed this app in BB10 device (chrome browser).